# Sefer of Kabbalistic sources of the mitzvots

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mitzvah, mysticism-kabbalah

I am looking for a book, in English, that elucidates the kabbalistic reasons for the mitzvos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find "Selections From Derech Mitzvotecha" by the 3rd Lubavitcher Rebbe, the Tzemach Tzedek of interest. Volume 1 can be read online at [Sichos in English](http://www.sie.org/templates/sie/article_cdo/aid/3139941).

There appears to be a second volume which is available for purchase through [Seforim Center](http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=4198&strReferer=search&PPGR=0).

[Volume 1](http://hebrewbooks.org/15419) and [Volume 2](http://hebrewbooks.org/15420) are available on hebrewbooks.org as well.

Comment: @Yaakov Deane Fantastic sefer! It's very clear and concise. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome Laya. I hope it serves you well.